# Time Limit execution of code for 30 days in Debian on RPI 4

Tags: debian, cron

I have to deliver my RPI4 to a customer for trial basis and i want to limit the execution of my code to either 100 times or make it time bound that it wont start after 30 days (a specific date). i have a I2C-RTC DS3231 installed in RPI.

I have checked `crontab` but I am not sure if it could be use to limit the execution after the date has passed.

Some notes

- The user will have no access to Pi. The code will start executing once Pi boots up.
- No internet access required for the application and no internet available around it either.

Is there a way I can limit end user on both number of execution and no execution after a specific date?

Comment: Will the Pi have access to the Internet when it’s being used by the customer?

Comment: The user will have no access to Pi. The code will start executing once Pi boots up.

Comment: No internet access required for the application and no internet available around it aswell.

Answer (score 1):

The issues you have asked about is not UNIX/Linux specific, and belongs in your application. The application is delivered as part of a turnkey system so you have quite a lot of flexibility.

What's not so easy is a method for handling the Pi specific issue that you didn't mention: that if the SD card is accessible then it becomes possible for someone to make unconfirmed changes to any file on the system. Including adding a root-equivalent account, enabling network access, or even bypassing your evaluation timeout code.

Any solution to handle that either requires that the SD card be unremovable (glue!), that you implement with security by obscurity, or that you add an additional package to your Pi to provide some sort of encryption/decryption/tokenisation service.

Also consider how to extend the licence period remotely - particularly without network access for the device. I've not suggested solutions for that here, but it could be a special menu option in your application to allow for a new licence file to be uploaded.

First off, have your customer sign a contract that limits them to your 100 uses or one month.

Then look at technical solutions. For example, implementing a licence file in your application.

To help protect against tampering, I would consider the following being shipped in that licence file as part of the initial package:

- There must be a termination date in the file set to a maximum possible value (say three months ahead)
- There must be a run counter := 0 in the file
- There must be a "secret hash" in the file of these two values. Such a "secret hash" must incorporate a secret that only your application knows

As the application starts, its rules might be:

- If there is no file then don't run
- If the file contains invalid data (including a mismatch of the date/counter values and the "secret hash") then don't run
- If the file conains valid data but has exceeded the termination date or number of runs then don't run
- If the run counter is zero, set the termination date to one month from today
- Increment the run counter
- Update the "secret hash"

Answer (score 0):

There are some Solutions for this specific Problem.
The most elegant way to solve it would be to create a script within your application. This script will start your actual Program/Code, whatever.

You can log all dates (current date and execute of program) in a SQL database or similar. There you can create a check if you have more than one hundred entries or if the first startup is longer than 30 days.
You could create an error message, where the customer needs to enter an activation key or whatever you create to unlock it again.

That would be the most corporate way. And it is possible to reuse this code.

Cheers